# Do I need a need to add om and namah when chanting the durga name or can be it done like radha or ram, just as the name?

Tags: durga

This may sound like a stupid question to all around. I have been trying to add naam japa of maa in my life. I’m just curios as to if it done with the full mantra always o”om durgaye namah” or is just chanting like we do for ram and or radha?

Comment: Om Durgayai namah is a mantra .. where as simply chanting "Durga. Durga' falls under nama japa .. in nama japa no need to add mantras or bijas simply chanting the name is enough...